# SUMIF for reciprocals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel, I am looking to calculate the sum of reciprocals for each number in the column, starting from that number.

Below works fine:

Ex: Below formula for each of the cell in second column

```
=SUM(1/A1:A6)
=SUM(1/A2:A6)
.
.
```

[image: Pic with no nulls]

But if I have a column with no value then it wont as the it treats nulls as zero and gets a divide by zero error.

[image: PicExcel]

If I use =SUMIF(1/J2:J6, ">0") then it's not working.

Any help to achieve this please?

Comment: You can use something like this and drag down from the first row: =SUM(IF(A1:$A$6<>"", 1/A1:$A$6, 0))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IFERROR`:

`=SUM(IFERROR(1/A1:A6,0))`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use dynamic arrays so `=SUM(FILTER(1/A1:A6,A1:A6<>0))` should work.

Comment: thanks for you response. I am using excel on mac and unfortunately it is saying that FILTER function is not available.